Not able to request docker container using eth1 interface IP
I have a vps on ec2 instance, It has eth0 interface by default and I have set up the eth1 interface on it by editing the yaml file and doing netplan apply, so the ip rule and ip route were added. I could ping and curl on both interfaces.
The problem arise when I have a docker container to run. I have 2 container block in the docker-compose.yaml file, in containerA, I have mapped the eth0 interface internal IP 172.31.33.191 on 80 port to the containerA port 4000. Similarly in containerB , I have mapped the eth1 interface internal IP 172.31.40.172 on 80 port to the containerB port 3000.
Now, when I ping using eth0 Internal IP on port 80, the request pass through and I get the result back. But when I ping using eth1 Internal IP on port 80, it is not able to make the connection at all.
What could be the issue here ?
1e793b073856   ubuntu-backend     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   10 hours ago   Up 10 hours               172.31.40.172:80->3000/tcp
This above doesn't work
05db9c4d7fca   ubuntu-backend2   "/codebase/app/ -p /a…"   10 hours ago   Up 10 hours               172.31.33.191:80->4000/tcp
This works
